# Not all instances of the if target statement are being changed when the Worksheet Change private sub runs in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

No errors are trapped, and the code compiles - leading me to think it's logic problem. The first 4 rows' formula in column A are changed, but nothing in subsequent columns (where all the rest of the formulas are), or any of the other rows.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Changes the row value in the worksheets' formulas to match the row value shown in B2 of the record the listbox(A2)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim lRow As String

If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then    'If the value of A2 changed, then
   lRow = Range("B2").Value                     'store the value of lRow - the line row value of the name that was selected in A2
   Worksheets("Student Report").Range("A3:Q104").Replace What:="$*", Replacement:=lRow, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False         'Replace any part of a cell that contains a $ and any number with the value in lRow
End If
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ";  " & Err.Description
Err.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this event macro part of `Worksheets("Student Report")`? If so, changing subsequent values on the same worksheet will get the `Worksheet_Change` to try and run on top of itself. Use `application.EnableEvents = false` to turn off events while you change values on the same worksheet then `application.EnableEvents = true` before exiting the sub.

Comment: It is.  I tried adding in the code (I can't believe I didn't think of it) but it didn't help.  I added the false statement after the If Target.Address line, and the true statement before the Exit Sub, and also after the Err.Clear line.  Still no dice.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the target address range to one cell eliminate the problem on having the event work on top of itself?  I set it to A2, the listbox, and the range the changes happen in is A3:Q104.  Unless I'm totally misunderstanding the Target.Address....which is entirely possible

Comment: Your `Target.Address` condition will stop the iterative changes from starting another `.Replace` routine, but at least one more instance of a `Worksheet_Change` is going to run on top of the original (even if it does nothing) and that is almost always ill-advised.

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to change something inside a formula that would effectively 'break' the formula and that throws an error which is caught by your error handler and the `Worksheet_Change` is exited. You need to provide examples of same formulas and the type of replacement value that would typically be found in B2.

Comment: The formula that it doesn't work on is an =IF formula.  The error handler isn't catching anything.  I didn't have one at first, and added it after the problem started to catch a code if it threw one.  It hasn't.  This is the formula in B2:  ="$"&(MATCH(A2,'Active Students'!G2:G290,0))+1 which results in displaying the dollar sign and row number of the value in A2.  A2 is a Data Validation list.

Comment: You are replacing part of the formula but you are looking at it as if you were changing part of the value. The formula is invalid and it throws out of the automated `.Replace` routine. You've only provided ¼ of the necessary information to provide a full solution but that formula replacement did help. Go back and experiment with manual Replace (aka `Ctrl+H`) until you have it working then record the action you used and look at the code that was produced. You have to account for the " with "" within a quoted string and you cannot have two equals signs in the post replacement formula.

Comment: Thank you!!!  Just needed to change to a ?? - didn't realize that it wouldn't replace the closing parenthesis if I was changing to a singe digit row reference.  By Jove it works!! Woohoo!!!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out. Post your solution as an answer and you can accept it as the answer to your problem 48 hours after posting. No problem with posting your own answer if you worked through the problem and I'll +1 it for having worked through to a solution yourself!

Comment: Nevermind.  didn't work. don't think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I worked out - it works, but isn't elegant.

One problem was using the * wildcard with replace.  the ? wildcard worked fine, but I had both single and double digit row numbers.  My solution to that was to insert 10 blank rows at above row 1 and hide them. Since my users will not have more than 90 students (the most will probably be 70) this workaround will work.  What:  "$??" works to replace the rows with the value in B2.

Here is my final code -

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Changes the row value in the worksheets' formulas to match the row value shown in B2 of the record the listbox(A2)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.EnableEvents = False

```
Dim lRow As String

If Target.Address = Range("A2").Address Then    'If the value of A2 changed, then

    lRow = Range("B2").Value                     'store the value of lRow - the line row value of the name that was selected in A2

    Worksheets("Student Report").Range("A3:Q104").Replace What:="$??", Replacement:=lRow, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False         'Replace any part of a cell that contains a $ and any number with the value in lRow

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
```

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ";  " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub